# mixture of complex gaussians

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I would like to compute the following probability

$$ P\left( ax \geq \sum_{i=1}^n b_i y_i  \right)  $$

where $a, b_i$ are constant coefficients (in my case, they are positive too) and $x, y_i$ are independent complex gaussian random variables with mean $0$ and variance $1$.

Comment: Do you really mean *complex* Gaussians? If so, mean, variance do not give full specification.

Comment: Could you mean *circularly symmetric* complex Gaussian, and be interested in the behaviour of *norms*, or maybe projections on the real axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like André Nicolas, I do not understand your use of *complex*, especially with the $\ge$ symbol.  So what follows ignores it. I will also use Capitals for random variables

$aX$ is a Gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and variance $a^2$.

Similarly $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i Y_i$ is a Gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and variance $\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2$ because of independence.

And $aX - \sum_{i=1}^n b_i Y_i$ is a Gaussian random variable with mean $0$ and variance $a^2+\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^2$ because of independence.

So $\Pr( aX \geq \sum_{i=1}^n b_i Y_i  ) = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I am really sorry, I don't know what I was thinking. I will edit the question in a while.